# Why javascript date.setDate() change the value of other date variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, variable-assignment

When i'm trying to know functionality of setDate() ,setTime() of javscript date i came across this problem.

```
<script>
var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date(1991,4,11);
var date3 = new Date(1992,4,11);

date3 = date1;
date2 = date1;
date2.setDate(date2 .getDate() + 40);//im changing only date2 value using setDate()  

//print values

</script>
```

I think the result will be like:
Fri Jul 04 2014
Wed Aug 13 2014
Fri Jul 04 2014

But in output all date variables have same value:

Wed Aug 13 2014

Wed Aug 13 2014

Wed Aug 13 2014

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Manirajss/4dSCf/)

If i do similar kind of code with integer variables they work like as i think(all int variables have different values).

**Summary of Questions**

1. How date assignment and number assignment differs?
2. Why and how javascript setDate() tracking other date variables?
3. Last but not least **What i have to do if i want to change only date2 value with these assignments?**

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to make a copy of your dates, like this:

```
date3 = new Date(date1.getTime());
date2 = new Date(date1.getTime());
```

or simply:

```
date3 = new Date(date1);
date2 = new Date(date1);
```

instead of

```
date3 = date1;
date2 = date1;
```

Otherwise, your variables all point to the same Date object (initially referenced by `date1`).

---

**EDIT** (about memory allocation)

  - Example 1:

```
var date1 = new Date();           // Memory allocation for an object
var date2 = new Date(1991,4,11);  // Memory allocation n°2
var date3;                        // Obviously no memory allocation here

date3 = date1;                    // No memory allocation either, date2 and date3
date2 = date1;                    // become references of the object in date1
```

In this example, there are two memory allocations but only one of them is useful as the object in date2 is not used.

**Note:** The object that was originally in date2 still exists, but is not referenced anymore (it will be garbage-collected).

  - Example 2:

```
var date1 = new Date();            // Memory allocation for an object
var date2 = new Date(date1);       // Memory allocation n°2
var date3 = new Date(date1);       // Memory allocation n°3
```

In this example, there are three memory allocations for ***3 different objects***. The 2nd and 3rd allocations consist in creating new Date objects, containing a copy of the object in date1.

---

I hope it is clearer with this little explanation. If you're interested in memory management in JavaScript, I suggest you have a look at this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: You don't need the `.getTime()` actually.

Comment: @Bergi Alright, I was not sure that new Date(date1) was a cross-browser solution

Comment: can you please explain something more about memory allocation in this case (How both assignments differ)?

Comment: I took some time to improve my answer by adding some explanations about memory allocation. Hope you like it! :)

Comment: Ha. didn't need the explanation, your first 3 lines answered my issue. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, Date is an object and "Fri Jul 04 2014" is only its contents. So when you do

```
date3 = date1;
```

you're saying:

let variable date3 point at the same object as variable date1. But there's still just one object with one content (e.g. your "Fri Jul 04 2014"). Whether you access it via
`date1.toDateString()` or `date3.toDateString()` doesn't matter. So when you change it using `date3.setDate()` or `date1.setDate();` doesn't matter as well.

What you need to do is build another object with the same content:

```
date3 = new Date(date1.getTime());
```

---

Imagine there's a room with one door (d1) and inside the room there's a white cat. When you say `d2 = d1`, you just build another door to the same room with the same white cat. If you call `d2.changeCat(black)`, then you're entering the room through the door d2 and changing the white cat for a black one. If you later access the room through the other door (d1), then you're just going to find the black cat, of course. And that's what happens.

What you need to do is build another room with another white cat instead, so when you change that cat for a black one later, it will not influence the white cat in the first room.

Comment: i'm yet to learn a lot of javascript!

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an object reference to date1 by doing the

```
date3 = date1;
date2 = date1;
```

So now, when using date2 for instance, you actually reference date object stored in date1 variable.